# Display alert if URL can't be opened

Tags: ios, swift, uialertcontroller, guard

I want to show an alert to users via `UIAlertController` when my app can't open a URL. Here's my code:

```
guard let url = URL(string: urlLink) else {
  return
}
UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:])
```

And my created alert:

```
let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Warning", message: "Problem with URL.", preferredStyle: .alert)
alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .default, handler: nil))
self.present(alert, animated: true)
```

If I move my alert inside the `guard` statement, it never occurs. I tested it by changing `urlLink` to some random `String`, for example, `"123"`. Any ideas of how I can show an alert?

**EDIT:**

I used `canOpenURL` which return `Bool`. Now my code is:

```
guard let url = URL(string: urlLink) else {
    return
}
if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url) {
    UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:])           
} else {
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Warning", message: "Problem with URL.", preferredStyle: .alert)
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .default, handler: nil))
    self.present(alert, animated: true)
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Should be before `return`

```
guard let url = URL(string: urlLink) , UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url) else {

  let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Warning", message: "Problem with URL.",   preferredStyle: .alert)
  alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .default, handler: nil))
  self.present(alert, animated: true)
  return
}
```

Comment: as i mentioned in my question it doesn't work or maybe i dont understand URL in swift.

Comment: @Sk_Khan  "If i move my alert inside guard statement it never occurs. I tested it by changing urlLink to some random string for example "123". "

Comment: @Sk_Khan u cant get acces to variable "url"

Comment: replace `&&` with `,`

Comment: Anyway i see that u use canOpenURL which return bool so i can use if after my guard statement.

Comment: @Sh_Khan Don't forget to run `UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:])` after your `guard` to actually open the valid URL.

Comment: @ZGski yes the op should handle it , i focused to the problem inside the `else`

Comment: @ShadeToD You don't really need the `if-else` statement after the `guard` if your code looks like the suggested answer.